# Ways to link two panels in different html templates

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am doing a patient-hospital app. I want to implement a function that the receptionist and the doctors can view schedules on that day. If the receptionist on her pc click on the panel which represents that patient check in for his or her appointment, the panel will change color to red. At the same time, the doctor's pc can see the change as well.

I think this function looks similar to the Observer pattern but I don't know how to implement it.

my Schedule model

```py
class Schedule(models.Model):
    checked_in = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    patient = models.OneToOneField('Patient', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='patient')
    date = models.DateField(db_column='date&time')  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    time = models.TimeField()
    doctorid = models.ForeignKey('Staff', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='doctorID', blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    waiting_time = models.TimeField(db_column='waiting time',blank=True,null=True)  # Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Schedule'
```

The panels which represent all the schedules on that day in the html

```html
{% if appoints %}
  {% for i in appoints %}
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">Appointment</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Patient: {{i.select_related('patient__user___first_name')}}{{i.select_related('patient__user___last_name')}}<br>
        Doctor: {{i.select_related('doctorid__user___first_name')}}{{select_related('doctorid__user___last_name')}}<br>
        Time: {{i.time}}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

js file responsible for the panels. ATTENTION: I am not certain about this js code of changing color, since I modified it from a button.

```
$('[class="panel-body"]').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('red'))
          $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

1. I wanna make checked_in=True after the receptionist click on it. How should I implement it?
2. In which way should I implement so that doctors and receptionist are can view the changes together (i.e. view the same panels)?
   Please provide me with details and explanations if possible since I am new to Django. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels) for this.

But first, you need to add the type of user in the `User` model. Then you can determine which type of user has logged in and then according to that you can change the content of the same panel.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=(("d", "Doctor"), ("p", "Patient"), ("r", "Receptionist")), max_length=1)  # update accordingly
```

Now that you can determine what type of user it is, you can use websockets to update the screen of the required user from the server, using django-channels.

I created a similar [project](https://github.com/amangarg078/deliveryapp) that is based on order delivery system, but the essence is the same - one user updates the state of an entity and the required user's screen is updated. You can take a reference and implement in your project according to your needs.

Now, to mark `checked_in=True`, you can make an api or a view which returns JSON response for that which takes the schedule's id and updates the flag. Then when the button is clicked, you can make an AJAX call to your endpoint, and update the flag.